# Retrieving drop down box selection in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to retrieve user selection from the following:

**UserInterface.php**

```
 <form name="formname" method="post" action="index.php">
    <div id='userList'>

        <?php
        //get constants for database
        require("database.php");

        // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
        $connection = mysqli_connect ($server, $username, $password);
        if (!$connection){  
            die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
            }

        // Set the active MySQL database
        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
        if (!$db_selected) {
            die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

        $query = "SELECT distinct user FROM route";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


            echo '<select name="box" style="width:400px;">';

                $count = 1;

               while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<option =".$count.">".$r['user']."</option>"; 
                $count++;
            }   
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Get Started!"/>
```

I wish to use it in `Map.php` where I will perform a sql query which in turn is used to produce XML.

**Map.php**

```
//get constants for database
require("database.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysqli_connect ($server, $username, $password);

//$user value dependant on user selection from dropdown menu
$query = "SELECT * FROM route WHERE user ='$selected'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result){
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

//set header to xml
\header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("alt", $row['alt']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("user", $row['user']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

`Map.php` is then used in `index.php` (my web main page where everything happens) as I use ajax to retrieve the xml from `Map.php` using `downloadUrl` method.

**index.php**

```
downloadUrl("Map.php", processXML);
```

I have been continually trying to get the drop down value back for use in `Map.php` but I cannot quite get it. I have looked at options such as:

```
$user = $_POST['box'];
```

and

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"] = $_POST['box'];
```

I have also tried posting the data straight to `Map.php` and redirecting to `index.php` but this did not work. I assume this may be because I am using `Map.php` within `index.php` thereby creating a loop of sorts?!

Is there a way to post the data to `Map.php` and then redirect to `index.php` only once?!

I apologise if this is incoherent and a bit of a mess, it's very late and I'm very stressed with this problem.

Any help or pointers would be truly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I have read this a few times...are you saying that you load up your index page and include the map page, but then after your index loads, when you change your selection you load up the maps page by itself (via ajax) and try to retrieve something from the map page to put into the index page as an update to what was originally the included map page (via include)?... *phew!*

Comment: echo "<option =".$count.">".$r['user']."</option>"; Are you missing a value attribute in the `<option tag> e.g <option value="1">optiontext</option>`

Comment: @Rasclatt - I am trying to go directly from UserInterface.php to index.php, but I want the drop down value from UserInteface.php to be used in Map.php...

Comment: You can do this easier than what you are trying I think

Comment: @Rasclatt - any idea how?!

Comment: Actually, I should ask a couple questions before I make a claim!! You can not really echo the contents of `Map.php` if you are trying to redirect so are you trying to echo the contents of `Map.php` on the index page or how are you wanting to deal with that?

Comment: I am not trying to echo map.php on index.php. In index.php, Map.php contents are retrieved using Ajax - downloadUrl(Map.php, function(data)...

Comment: Is this page public facing to take a look at?

Comment: It is on github - fstaylor104 - Main.

Comment: @Rasclatt - Got it sorted - using a session variable to get the POST value in index and just accessing that in map.php. to do my query

Comment: Yeah I was going to say use a session but I have to admit.....I still wasn't 100% sure I knew what you were trying to do based on your description(s) but I didn't want to keep asking you the same clarifying questions over and over....! Anyway glad you got it working!!